# Error handling special characters using utfOffset16

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have a function that searches and returns the index within the string of the first occurrence of `searchStr`, however I keep getting a fatal error whenever the string contains any special charactsers (such as ç or é). The error seems to be occuring at the utf16Offset call and I can't seem to figure out why.. here is the code I'm using:

```
func index(of aString: String, startingFrom position: Int? = 0) -> String.Index? {
    guard let position = position else {
        return nil
    }

    if self.startIndex.utf16Offset(in: aString) + position > self.endIndex.utf16Offset(in: aString) {
        return nil
    } // produces fatal error when special character encountered

    let start: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: position)
    let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: self.endIndex))
    return self.range(of: aString, options: .literal, range: range, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
}
```

Comment: I guess the obvious question is why you would try to cycle thru a string using `utf16Offset`.  Also, why are you writing a method that is already a solved problem? Is it just an exercise?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by solved problem? This method is part of a library I'm using to compare 2 strings and its causing a fatal error that I'm trying to diagnose... I'm trying to fix or prevent this fatal error

Comment: But you didn’t say any of that in the question. The question implies this is your code. — Anyway I would suggest that you upgrade to Swift 5 and, if necessary, abandon use of this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part seems problematic to me

```
if self.startIndex.utf16Offset(in: aString) + position > self.endIndex.utf16Offset(in: aString) {
    return nil
}
```

You're taking the start index on `self` and convert it to its UTF-16 offset in `aString`. `self` and `aString` are two unrelated strings though so this is probably undefined behavior (which might be why you see it crashing in some cases).

The intent of this `if` statement seems to be to ensure that this produces a valid range (`lower <= upper`)

```
let start: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: position)
let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: self.endIndex))
```

You can actually do that by just comparing the `Index`es directly like this

```
let start: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: position)

guard start < self.endIndex else {
    return nil
}

// Range is guaranteed to have valid boundaries now
let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: self.endIndex))
```

Full example:

```
extension String {
    func index(of aString: String, startingFrom position: Int? = 0) -> String.Index? {
        guard let position = position else {
            return nil
        }

        let start: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: position)

        guard start < self.endIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: self.endIndex))
        return self.range(of: aString, options: .literal, range: range, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
    }
}

// Doesn't crash anymore
"aaç".distance(from: foobar.startIndex, to: foobar.index(of: "ç", startingFrom: 0)!)
```